# is it possible to copy pw from /sbin/ in FreeBSD to /sbin/ in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, freebsd

I was wondering if it's possible to copy this file to Linux hence when I type it on the terminal app it returns unknown command so I copied it from FreeBSD 12.1 to RHEL8/Fedora 31 and changed its permission to 777 
i've copied it `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin/` 
but it returns 
sh: /usr/sbin/pw: No such file or directory
is there any way to make it works under Linux

Comment: If it is a _script_, possibly (it depends on what tools the script uses). If it is a compiled binary file, then it is very unlikely to work on Linux. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293770/nix-executable-compatibility/293776  You'd be better off installing it from your package manager, or recompiling it from sources.

Comment: Changing a system program's permission to 777 (everyone can modify the file) is not at all sensible. At most it should be 775 and probably just 755.

Comment: @Kusalananda here's the source code of FreeBSD https://github.com/Goharleone/freebsd but I can't clone the source code of pw only, is there a way to download https://github.com/Goharleone/freebsd/tree/master/usr.sbin/pw only

Comment: @roaima i want to run this utility  frist

Comment: The utility you're looking at is very specific to FreeBSD. It would not even work on other types of BSD system without a bit of effort porting it. You would be better served by using some similar utility written for Linux. A real answer should probably mention such Linux-specific alternatives.

Comment: @Kusalananda I can't get the source code to dig around with it.

Comment: @AhmedElGohary The code depends on other parts of the FreeBSD code (headers and such) and infrastructure, available on an installed FreeBSD system. A BSD system is a complete unit, checking out a single utility does not make sense. If you just want to _read_ the code, it is available on Github. The code is also [available via Subversion](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/), but I don't know that tool so I can't say whether checking out a single directory is possible.

Comment: the kernel calls are completely different

Comment: @AhmedElGohary I would be surprised if they were the same. The FreeBSD and Linux kernels are totally different from each other.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's a good point to know the effort taken by a developer to port an app from os to another one.but I loved FreeBSD more than Linux. the only UNIX I've tried is macOS (i know that FreeBSD is a Unix). but I wanna try AIX :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeBSD [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pw(8)) tells me this is an utility to manage users and groups. All Linux distributions (and most Unices I know) have some special toolset for this, in Linux' case often derived from Debian's shadow-utils. Learn to use the native way of doing things!

Such a tool depends intimately on the target's layout (how the relevant files are called, where they are located, any protocol to follow when manipulating them; are they files in the first place or does the data live e.g. in LDAP or even NIS). As this is not particularly performance critical, it could even be a script (but those are easily highjacked, so...), it will probably call a herd of low-level programs to to the real work (or might do it directly instead of invoking e.g. passwd(1)).

This is open source, so you are welcome to port the tool to your system. But I'd start at the official user interface, i.e., the manual page. Too much of what has to be done will be different.